# $A_n \cap A_m$ has exactly n + m elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Find an infinite family $A$ of infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ such that for each $A_n, A_m$ holds that $A_n \cap A_m$ has exactly n + m elements

My idea was to split $\mathbb{N}$ in such a way that it is fulfilled, but so far I have not managed to formalize this idea.

Comment: This is impossible. Indeed, the condition gives that $A_1 \cap A_1$ must have only two elements, but $A_1$ is also asked to be infinite.

Comment: (Assuming the requirement is to be valid when $m\neq n$.) Start by making $A_1, A_2$ and $A_3$. Then see if you can construct those in a way so it's obvious how to keep going with $A_4,A_5$ and so on.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I guess the condition should only be required when $m\neq n$.

Comment: @ArnaudD. I guess the same thing, but we are not here to *guess* what the OP wants to say.

Comment: The greedy algorithm works.  Put 1,2,3 in both $A_1$ and $A_2$.  Then 4,5,6,7 in $A_1$ and $A_3$, the next five in $A_1$ and $A_4$, then five in $A_2$ and $A_3$ ...

Comment: Indeed, it is when $m \neq n$

Comment: @Empy2 Could you be a little clearer please? I think I understand a bit, but how are the sets?

Comment: The tags have a little description to them, and you can read it and decide if the tag fits the question. There's no reason to just senselessly add all the tags that are "set-theory".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a countably infinite set of pairs $\{A_m,A_n\}$.  You also have an endless supply of numbers to put in the $A_n$.  My suggested sets are:
$$A_1=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12\ldots\}   \\
A_2=\{1,2,3,13,14,15,16,17,\ldots\}   \\
A_3=\{4,5,6,7,13,14,15,16,17,\ldots\}  \\
A_4=\{8,9,10,11,12,\ldots\} $$
Then 18-23 go in $A_1$ and $A_5$, 24-29 in $A_2$ and $A_4$, and so on.

Answer (score -1):

I think you cannot find any such example.

That is because of the following reasons.

1-$A_n \cap A_n$ has $n+n=2n$ elements. Hence every $A_n$ must be a finite set

2-$A_n \cap A_{2n}$ has $n+2n=3n$ elements

3-$3n=|A_n \cap A_{2n} |<|A_n|=2n$ since $A_n \cap A_{2n} \subset A_n  \Rightarrow \Leftarrow $